# You tube API for editing videos

Tags: youtube-api

Is You tube API methods allow to edit videos or merge videos dynamically while uploading videos directly?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Read this http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading.html